# Will if(dispatcherClass.hasEventListener(EventType) return true if the calling class is not subscribed but other listeners are?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

The 'hasEventListener() method only accepts a single parameter (the event type).  Will this prevent a class that calls:

```
if(!myDispatcherClass.hasEventListener(myEvent)){
   myDispatcherClass.addEventListener(myEvent, myHandlerFunction)
)
```

from being subscribed if a different class has already called an identical function?

Comment: are you mixing up `instances` and `classes`?

Comment: Though from what I think you're asking, the answer is yes.  But your code doesn't do what you think it does.  If should be `if(!myDispatcherInstance.hasEventListener(myEvent)){`

Comment: For me, "different class" means different instance. And **no** it won't prevent it if different instance already has an event. `hasEventListener` works for **particular** instance and doesn't know about any other class. So it will return **TRUE** if your **current** instance **has** such listener attached.

Comment: there are 2 different circumstances  where i use hasEventListener:  1) in cases where I only want to subscribe if the is no other handler, (for instance, if I make a server request, to prevent repeating the same request) or 2) to avoid duplicate listeners   The two, however seem mutually exclusive

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate listeners? If you have an instance of loader and add the same listener twice - the function will be executed **only once**!

Comment: exactly, this func is useless:) you can have onEnterFrame on the same instance more than once, and if you want to test with this function you will not know which listener but if there is any listener. I stopped using it loooong time ago, instead before registering event I always unregister it.